# Does sharding cause eventual consistency for MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

If I enable sharding for MongoDb, will queries become eventually consistent? If not, what do I lose by enabling sharding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sharding is not eventually consistent, unless you specifically use a non-primary read preference.

When you enable sharding you need to add mongos query routers and a config server replica set.  Each document will be stored in only 1 of the shards, with databases and collections spread across the shards.  Instead of directly querying a single replica set, all reads and writes must go through a mongos to be routed to the shard(s) that holds the document(s).  The drawbacks of sharding are this layer of complexity and the additional nodes required.